# Magento 2 : Show loader till all ajax call not completed

Tags: magento2, ajax

I want to show `loader` till page not loaded or all `Ajax` call not completed in **frontend** and **backend** both side.

Is it possible in Magento 2.0.7 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-requests-are-done

Answer (score 20):

You can try below ajax call for showing loader during ajax call is runnig.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    showLoader: true //use for display loader 
}).done(function (data) {
    return true;
});
```

Comment: I want to call this for default ajax calling in Magento 2. I dont want to call my ajax.

Comment: use can use ajaxStart() and ajaxComplete() function for show and display loader.

Comment: I tried ajaxComplete() and ajaxStop() but both not working, don't know why.

Comment: Try my solution (I had the same question) https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/171485/40609